# Basis and subbasis for the standard topology on $[0,\infty)$

Tags: general-topology

I know the typical basis element for the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is $(a, b)$ where $a<b$. But how about the case for standard topology on $[0,\infty)$? What can be a example of a basis for the standard topology on $[0,\infty)$? Also can anyone give me a example of sub basis for the standard topology on $[0,\infty)$ that is not a basis?

Answer (score 1):

You just take the intervals $[0,a)$ ($a>0$) together with the intervals $(a,b)$ ($0<a<b$). That's a base.

An example of a subbase which is *not* a base is the set of all intervals $[0,a)$ ($a>0$) together with the intervals $(a,\infty)$ ($a>0$ too).

Comment: I see. Thanks! How about the subbasis?

Comment: I have added that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The standard subbase for any ordered space $(X,<)$ are all upper and lower sets

$$a^\downarrow = \{x \in X: x < a\}; a^\uparrow = \{x \in X: x > a\}$$

where $a$ ranges over all of $X$.

For $[0,\infty)$ these are

$$[0,a), (a, +\infty); a \ge 0$$

and a base is formed by all finite intersections from the subbase, and this adds as new sets all open intervals $[0,a) \cap (b, +\infty)=(a,b)$ where $0 \le a < b$.